# A confusion about Lie group of two dim non abelian real Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

In the book by Fulton & Harris (chapter 10, section 1) :

> Finally, in the real case things are simpler: when we exponentiate the
> adjoint representation as above, the Lie group we arrive at is already simply
> connected, and so is the unique connected real Lie group with this Lie algebra.

Just to give background : It has been shown that there exist a unique non abelian two dimensional Lie algebra with basis $\{X,Y \}$ such that $[X,Y]= X.$ They calculate the adjoint form by exponenting the lie algebra to find $G_0 = \{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ 0 & 1\\  \end{pmatrix} : a \ne 0 \} $. Is it not true that  over real numbers $G_0$ would be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R \times S^1?$

I am not able to make sense of what exactly they are telling the above quoted paragraph.

Comment: $\mathbb R \times S^1 $ is not simply connected right?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I made a mistake. Let me write an answer that is actually correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula for $G_0$ has some issues.

First, the quantity $b$ has not been specified. You seem to have assumed $b$ takes values in $S^1$, but it should instead take values in $\mathbb R$. Making that correction we get
$$G_0 = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ 0 & 1\\  \end{pmatrix} : a  \in \mathbb R - \{0\}, \, b \in \mathbb R \right\} 
$$

This leads to the second issue. With that correction it follows that $G_0$ is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb R - \{0\}) \times \mathbb R$, which is not even connected, and so certainly not simply connected. But this can also be corrected, by instead specifying $a \in \mathbb R_+$:
$$G_0 = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ 0 & 1\\  \end{pmatrix} : a  \in \mathbb R_+, \, b \in \mathbb R \right\} 
$$
And now $G_0$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R$ which is indeed simply connected.

One last comment: it's true that $\mathbb R - \{0\}$ and $\mathbb R_+$ have isomorphic Lie algebras, but only the second one is simply connected. It's also true that $S^1$ and $\mathbb R$ have isomorphic Lie algebras, but only the second one is simply connected. So if you want the topological product to be simply connected, pick the simply connected factors.